# Unhandled exception - 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'SelectAllCheckBoxes' is undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm new to web development so I'm still learning the fundamentals.

I just want to add some jQuery to my ASP .NET page.

In the header, I reference what I need:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/HeaderCheckBoxSelections.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is what the `~/HeaderCheckBoxSelections.js` looks like:

```
function SelectAllCheckBoxes(cbSelect) {
    $('#<%=gvShows.ClientID%>').find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if (this != cbSelect) {
            this.checked = cbSelect.checked;
        }
    });
}
```

The event is triggered by this:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckBoxes(this);"/>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

But when the check box is clicked, it says:

Unhandled exception...

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'SelectAllCheckBoxes' is undefined.
```

Am I missing something here? Am I not referencing jQuery properly?

Comment: When your page loads, do you see any errors in the browser console? (Also that `~` in the `<script>` URL looks fishy to me, but perhaps it's an ASP thing.)

Comment: I would be willing to bet, you are getting a 404 on HeaderCheckBoxSelections.js?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a 404. I just get an Unhandled exception at the "onclick" event for that checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the databinding in the jquery selector in

> $('#<%=grdOperation.ClientID%>')

won't work in a separate javascript file. That databinding has to be on the aspx markup to be rendered correctly.

You can either move that databinding into your aspx by storing it to a variable, such as

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/HeaderCheckBoxSelections.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var grdOperationId = '<%=grdOperation.ClientID%>';
    </script>
</head>
```

and then referencing it by variable in your javascript.

Or you can use an "id ends with" selector to select it in the js code, as long as there is only one grdOperation on the page. Such as:

```
function SelectAllCheckBoxes(cbSelect) {
    $('[id$=grdOperation]').find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if (this != cbSelect) {
            this.checked = cbSelect.checked;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have suggested in my answer to use a `jQuery class` selector instead just to prove this.

Comment: You could also ( IF you are using ASP.net 4.0 ) set the ClientId="Static" for the gridView and then use the id set in your mark up.  If you are looking to keep JS seperate.  Be warned though if you control is repeated it could cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="SelectAllCheckBoxes(this);"/>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

The ASP.NET `Checkbox` control does not actually have an `OnClick attribute`, nor an `OnClientClick attribute`; thus ASP.NET just passes the attribute on like a custom attribute and since a browser knows what to do with an `onclick` attribute it tries to execute the logic.

If this fails, then it is a problem with the actual `.js` file being loaded correctly. Can you verify with `Chrome Developer Tools`, `Firebug` or `IE F12 Tools` that the `.js` file is actually in memory?

Here is a screenshot of `Chrome Developer Tools` filtering out just the `Scripts`, in the `Network` tab, upon going to [Microsoft's web site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx):

[image]

Comment: now I'm getting this: Unhandled exception at line 4, column 15226 in http://localhost/TVData/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%gvShows.ClientID%>

Comment: What browser are you running this on?

Comment: I'm using IE 9. I'll try to open this with Chrome

Comment: ok chrome does not give me an error but when I click the header checkbox, the other check boxes in the column are not being checked...

Comment: If you apply a `class` to the `GridView`, such as `ThisGrid` and use a `jQuery` selector by class name instead of by ID, does it work?